# Notify section on teams should remove cursor:pointer;

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

The Notify section has `cursor:pointer` which should be removed as there is no reason for it (it's not a URL, and there isn't a title or tooltip associated with it).

[image: Pointer cursor for the header of Notify]

Comment: Lack of red freehand circle makes it kinda difficult to detect the exact location of probem so -0.5

Comment: looks like a bug indeed! adding it to our list.

Answer (score 2):

Just pushed a fix for this, so it should be live with our next prod build. Thanks for the report!